# How to make a C# REST request using a Google Cloud JSON Service account file?

Tags: c#, rest, gcloud

I'd like to leverage the new Google TTS using a simple rest request. To that end, I've created a Service Account which downloaded a JSON file containing a private key id, a private key, client email, client id, client_x509_cert_url, etc.

I've also set the environment variable for the system:

```
 Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", jsonFile);
```

I then found this sample CURL request to use the WaveNet TTS engine provided by Google:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) \
-H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
--data "{
'input':{
  'text':'Android is a mobile operating system developed by Google,
     based on the Linux kernel and designed primarily for
     touchscreen mobile devices such as smartphones and tablets.'
},
'voice':{
  'languageCode':'en-gb',
  'name':'en-GB-Standard-A',
  'ssmlGender':'FEMALE'
},
'audioConfig':{
  'audioEncoding':'MP3'
}
}" "https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1beta1/text:synthesize" > writtenfile.txt
```

I want to create a simple C# webrequest from the above CURL request, but the line *"gcloud auth application-default print-access-token"* is a problem for me. I cannot install a CLI gcloud instance on this machine. Isn't there some way to setup the webrequest authorization access token from the JSON service account file? Surely I don't HAVE to have gcloud installed.

Looking for code sample demonstrating how to convert CURL code to a C# rest request using the service account json file without gcloud.

Comment: Not sure about your specific case, but I have used something like `GoogleCredential googleCredential = GoogleCredential.FromJson(Constants.CRED_JSON);
            Channel channel = new Channel(SpeechClient.DefaultEndpoint.Host, googleCredential.ToChannelCredentials());` to connect to google speech services

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't want to install the `gcloud` packages, you can execute **REST** calls by using **API Keys**. These keys can be [created directly in the GCP console](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys#creating_an_api_key) and they can be passed as a parameter through the request header; in this way, you can authenticate to the service without the need of `gcloud`. Additionally, I suggest you to take a look on this [guide](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/497123/How-to-make-REST-requests-with-Csharp) that contains the steps required to make REST requests with C#.

You can use this [Restlet Client tool](https://client.restlet.com/) to test the following example:

**REST content Example**

- Header

`https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1beta1/text:synthesize?key=<YOUR_API_KEY>`

- Body

`{
    'input':{
      'text':'Android is a mobile operating system developed by Google,
         based on the Linux kernel and designed primarily for
         touchscreen mobile devices such as smartphones and tablets.'
    },
    'voice':{
      'languageCode':'en-gb',
      'name':'en-GB-Standard-A',
      'ssmlGender':'FEMALE'
    },
    'audioConfig':{
      'audioEncoding':'MP3'
    }
  }`

Finally, in case you want to consume a Service Account JSON file, you can use the **Client libraries** to [create and send your TTS requests](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#create_audio_data) to then [authenticate them directly from your code](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#obtaining_and_providing_service_account_credentials_manually); however, this method require to install the TextToSpeech packages.